# Drone land survey path planning

Tags: java, c++, c, algorithms

I am working on a drone mission planner app similar to [Pix4dcapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pix4d.pix4dmapper&hl=en_IN&gl=US) and [Drone Harmony](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droneharmony.planner&hl=en_IN&gl=US). Is there any Java/C/CPP library that helps in computing the lawnmower path of the drone given the vertices of the polygon in which the path is to be traced? Something similar to [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mavlink/qgroundcontrol/master/src/MissionManager/SurveyPlanCreator.png)